# Change or Remove an Attribute

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xslt, xpath, transform

I have an XML document that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Schema Namespace="EDIManagement.Models.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2008" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator">
  <EntityType Name="AccountRemark">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="AccountRemarkId" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="AccountRemarkId" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
    <Property Name="AccountId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="RemarkTypeId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="RemarkEnteredAt" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="EnteredBy" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100" />
    <Property Name="Remark" Type="nvarchar(max)" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="LastEditedBy" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100" />
  </EntityType>
</Schema>
```

I am trying to transform it with XSLT so that the new document is identical, with just one line of difference.  The line to be changed is this:

```
    <Property Name="Remark" Type="nvarchar(max)" Nullable="false" />
```

It should be transformed into this:

```
    <Property Name="Remark" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="300" />
```

My XSLT transform so far looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
  xmlns:def="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"  />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="def:EntityType/def:Property[@Type='nvarchar(max)']/@*" >
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@Type='nvarchar(max)'">
        <xsl:attribute name="Type">nvarchar</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="MaxLength">300</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy></xsl:copy>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm stepping through the transform with Visual Studio 2010 debugging, and I see that it correctly activates the `[@Type='nvarchar(max)']/@*` template.  The only problem is that the `xsl:when test="@Type='nvarchar(max)'"` never tests as true.  Of course this is bizarre, because if the template itself matched, then this identical condition should match as well.

But because the `when` test strangely doesn't become true, my target doesn't get transformed at all, and I simply end up with an exact copy of the original document.  If I change the when clause to `xsl:when test="1=1"` then it finally tests as true, which demonstrates that overall the transform is correct.  But this still begs the question: why is the proper expression never becoming true?

I'm just simply unable to figure why the proper test expression never becomes true.  Ideas?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of the problem and for complete and easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this template:

```
<xsl:template match="def:EntityType/def:Property[@Type = 'nvarchar(max)']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="Type">nvarchar</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="MaxLength">300</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Wow!  Good trick.  I think the above template attempts to add duplicate attributes, but the XML generation won't allow duplicates.  As a consequence, this template gets away with being very compact!

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is in this code**:

```
    <xsl:template match="def:EntityType/def:Property[@Type='nvarchar(max)']/@*" >
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@Type='nvarchar(max)'">
                <xsl:attribute name="Type">nvarchar</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="MaxLength">300</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy></xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

This line: `<xsl:when test="@Type='nvarchar(max)'">`

tests if the current (matched) node has an attribute named `Type` that has a specific value. However, only elements can have attributes and attributes never have attributes themselves. Therefore the comparison is always `false()`.

**One possible solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl def"
 xmlns:def="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"  />
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "def:EntityType/def:Property
          [@Type='nvarchar(max)']" >
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
     <xsl:attribute name="Type">nvarchar</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="MaxLength">300</xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Schema Namespace="EDIManagement.Models.Store"
  Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient"
  ProviderManifestToken="2008"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl"
  xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator">
    <EntityType Name="AccountRemark">
        <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="AccountRemarkId" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="AccountRemarkId" Type="int"
                  Nullable="false"
                  StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
        <Property Name="AccountId" Type="int"
                  Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="RemarkTypeId" Type="int"
                  Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="RemarkEnteredAt" Type="datetime"
                  Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="EnteredBy" Type="nvarchar"
                  Nullable="false" MaxLength="100" />
        <Property Name="Remark" Type="nvarchar(max)"
                  Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="LastEditedBy" Type="nvarchar"
                  Nullable="false" MaxLength="100" />
    </EntityType>
</Schema>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" Namespace="EDIManagement.Models.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2008">
   <EntityType Name="AccountRemark">
      <Key>
         <PropertyRef Name="AccountRemarkId"/>
      </Key>
      <Property Name="AccountRemarkId" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"/>
      <Property Name="AccountId" Type="int" Nullable="false"/>
      <Property Name="RemarkTypeId" Type="int" Nullable="false"/>
      <Property Name="RemarkEnteredAt" Type="datetime" Nullable="false"/>
      <Property Name="EnteredBy" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100"/>
      <Property Name="Remark" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="300"/>
      <Property Name="LastEditedBy" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100"/>
   </EntityType>
</Schema>
```